# Generated <ion-selected-option>'s value taking priority over <ion-select>'s placeholder

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My problem is (apparently) simple. This is the result I would like to achieve :

[image]

I manage to get this result with the following code (`home.page.html`) :

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Type</ion-label>
  <ion-select formControlName="type" placeholder="Insert your type here...">
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Now, when I add some ion-selected-option for this ion-select, like this :

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Type</ion-label>
  <ion-select formControlName="type" placeholder="Insert your type here...">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

the placeholder is replaced by the value of the first ion-selected-option when the page loads.

[image]

The values of these `ion-selected-option` are declared in the constructor of my home.page.ts like such :

```
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.types = [
      "Advert",
      "OOH/POS simple",
      "OOH/POS complex",
      "Other"
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by looking in my formBuilder in `home.page.ts`, the line that caused this behavior was as follows:

```
 this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
 ...
 type: new FormControl(this.types[0], Validators.required),
 ...
 })
```

So I replaced it by :

```
 type: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
```

And so, I found back the placeholder.